# How can I generate n random numbers without a for loop

Tags: python, random, python-itertools

I am trying to generate 4 random integers between 0-9.
I can easily achieve this *using* a for-loop:

```
digits = [random.randrange(10) for i in range(4)]
```

Assuming it is possible, I was wondering about other ways to yield the same result, perhaps without directly using a for-loop. I was experimenting with itertools and *this didn't* work:

```
digits = itertools.repeat(random.randrange(10), 4)
```

The main purpose of my question is to expose myself to additional methods.
Thanks.

Comment: In Python 3.6 - there's also `random.choices`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
numpy.random.randint(0, 10, size=4)
```

or to use itertools

```
list(map(random.randrange, itertools.repeat(10, 4)))
```

or even

```
list(map(random.randrange, [10]*4))
```

Comment: You don't need `itertools`: `list(map(random.randrange, [10]*4))`

Answer (score 1):

What about using a generator and a `while loop` ?

```
from random import randrange

def rand(val, repeat=4):
    j = 1
    while j <= repeat:
        yield randrange(val)
        j += 1

final = list(rand(10))
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 8, 8]
```

Also, using a `recursion`:

```
from random import randrange

def rand(val, repeat=4, b=1, temp=[]):
    if b < repeat:
        temp.append(randrange(val))
        return rand(val, b= b+1, temp=temp)
    else:
        return temp + [randrange(val)]

final = rand(10)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
[1, 9, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really something that I would do, but since you would like to expose yourself to additional methods, then taking advantage of the 0-9 range you can also obtain 4 such integers as follows:

```
map(int, "%04d"%random.randrange(10**4))
```

It actually generates a four digit string, and extracts the digits from it.

Comment: Definitely unconventional, but interesting approach!